# Writing functions that can convert types in pyopencl

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I'm trying to write some additional functions for the COMPLEX (cfloat_t) type in pyopencl. I have practically no experience with OpenCL and am getting a bit bogged down by syntax. I'd like to write a few basic functions that could take in REAL inputs (floats in this case) and convert them to the COMPLEX type. For example Euler's formula e^ix = cos(x) + isin(x) with x as a REAL input

I thought this would be something like

```
#include <pyopencl-complex.h>    
#define REAL      float
#define COMPLEX   cfloat_t
COMPLEX c_exp_i(REAL x)        {return (COMPLEX)(cos(x), sin(x));}
```

But when I attempt to run this I see an error message

```
error: cast to union type from type 'float' not present in union
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading pyopencl-complex.h, I've realized there is a cfloat_new() function which solves everything

```
COMPLEX c_exp_i(REAL x)     {return cfloat_new(cos(x), sin(x));}
```